# Post request worked but redirects to error page

Tags: javascript, json, post, vue.js, axios

I'm having a weird issue when I'm performing a POST request. I have 3 differents forms with post method on the same page, the first one works perfectly.

The two others seems to have a problem : when I hit the save button it redirects on an error page with `Cannot POST /http://localhost:4000/cards`. The url of the page is `http://localhost:8080/http://localhost:4000/cards` which is my local server url + the json server url.

When I refresh the page, the request has worked because a new card is added.

Here is my simplified code :

```
<form action="/http://localhost:4000/teamsettings" method="POST">
  <input name="title" class="input-source" v-model="teamsetting.name" type="text">
  <input name="description" class="input-source" v-model="teamsetting.description" type="text">

 <div type="submit" @click="submitTeamG(teamsetting)">Save</div>
</form>



<form action="/http://localhost:4000/cards" method="POST">
  <input v-model="title">
  <textarea class="input-resume" v-model="description"></textarea>

  <button type="submit" @click="subCard">Save</button>
</form>



<form action="/http://localhost:4000/cards" method="POST">
  <input v-model="card.title">
  <textarea class="input-resume" v-model="card.description"></textarea>

  <button type="submit" @click="modifyCard">Modify</button>
</form>
```

And here are my axios posts requests :

```
methods: {
        submitTeamG(teamsetting) {
            axios.put('http://localhost:4000/teamsettings', {
                name: teamsetting.name,
                description: teamsetting.description
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            window.location="/backoffice";
        },

        subCard() {
            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/cards', {
                title: this.title,
                description: this.description,
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            window.location="/backoffice";
        },

        modifyCard(card) {
            axios.put('http://localhost:4000/cards', {
                title: card.title,
                description: card.description,
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            window.location.reload();
        }
    },
```

I can see in the console a 404 error before the redirection to error page, but new data is added in the database json file. What is this issue?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Instad of  `window.location="/backoffice";` use `window.open("/backoffice","_self");`

Comment: Thank you fofr your reply! It didn't change anything tho

Comment: please try it once.

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere else, because the first post request works just fine. On the two others, I have a error 404 in the console before it redirects to the error page. But I can see that the data is added into the db

Comment: you have issue at server side. So please update question with java servicce code. So that we can rectify issue.